# Why when I turn the one knob kitchen Facet from running cold water to hot water does the water stop?

Tags: plumbing, hot-water, kitchen-sink

We just got home from a weekend away.  We actually dropped the house temperature while we were away from 70 C to 58 C (outside it was actually the coldest its been all season (-30 C)
When we got home our Kitchen Facet - which is a single knob facet - wasn't working properly.
When I ran it on cold water it runs normally - when I turn the facet to hot water the water shuts off completely.  Could it be that our hot water line froze?  Every other facet in the house works properly - so it isn't the hot water tank.  Any suggestions before I call a professional?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a frozen pipe to me. If you can, you should turn the water off to that section of plumbing. At least until you can verify the plumbing has not been damaged.